# What is the best way to have image uploading and cropping in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, paperclip, jcrop

I want to upload an image to a model and then crop it. I tried using paperclip with jcrop, but I can not figure it out. Any other options out there?

Comment: "but I can not figure it out" - thats a little vague. What were your exact problems? Paperclip and CarrierWave are 2 of the biggest names. Paperclip is pretty awesome. I havent used CarrierWave.

Comment: when I had to implement the same functionality I went exactly with paperclip and jcrop - I don't think there's easier solution around. Will be glad to help with any paperclip/jcrop questions though

Comment: sorry, my brain was fried when I wrote this. Basically I have been wrestling with the paperclip/jcrop railscast tutorial. Everything works perfectly except that the image is not actually being cropped. I keep getting a nomethod error when it tries to run the cropper processor. It says it is trying to run a private method called sub.  I was hoping that by asking this question someone might point me to a different tutorial cause I am burned out on this railscast one. I feel like I have tried everything. Do you know of a different tutorial other than the railscast one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dragonfly` + `jcrop`.
You can see a good example here: https://github.com/jschwindt/dragonfly_crop

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout http://odysseyonrails.com/articles/10. It has a demo code using paperclip and jcrop.

Comment: Link only answers aren't very good, what if the link no longer works? Please consider copying the relevant content from it and keeping the link as a reference.